# Run dialog box when app launches

Tags: .net, vb.net, dialog

I want launch a dialog box to prompt the user for website credentials, am i able to design the dialog box like normal VB windows?

Comment: What do you mean "normal vb windows"?

Comment: like you know how you can use toolbox to create a vb window? adding labels and lists and buttons? or do i have to run the dialog as the default looking like dialog. i was hoping to make it look nicer and all and well generally get it working...

Comment: Is this a web site, or a WinForms app, WPF?

Comment: no no its just a normal application, ok let me explain it better. This app has to logon to a http website and download files for analysis. so i thought have a dialog box to come up to get the http credentials, and then if all is good start the main application which downloads files and shows the results of the analysis. just as an fyi, im an intern and this is my first time using vb, though i have good enough knowledge of most main programming languages :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to turn off the Windows Application Framework in the project properties.  Then set your start up object to `Sub Main`.  Then create a 'Public Sub Main" in a module (not a class).  That will then be the entry point to your application.  Then do something like this:

```
Module Main
    Public Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Dim login as LoginForm = New LoginForm()
        Application.Run(login)
        If login.Sucessful Then
            Application.Run(New MainForm())
        End If
    End Main
End Module
```

Comment: wow loads of great suggestions, thanks very much to everyone, i shall try and see which one suits best for the application :) also seeing as were helping poor 'ol me here (ha) how can i input credentials to a site without having to open a browser, is it done like entering an ftp url where u can put user, pass and then the link to the server? orrrrr...

Comment: @MakarEmelyanov, Sounds like a great idea for a new question on stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Create your form using the designer like you want.

Call it in your application like:

```
myForm.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Comment: wow loads of great suggestions, thanks very much to everyone, i shall try and see which one suits best for the application :) also seeing as were helping poor 'ol me here (ha) how can i input credentials to a site without having to open a browser, is it done like entering an ftp url where u can put user, pass and then the link to the server? orrrrr...

Comment: Sounds like a great idea for a new question on stack overflow :)

Comment: @SteveDog You need to direct the answer toward him or he will not see it.

Comment: no no i see :) i agree, but now ive come to another impass, now im told that the application has to keep checking to see if it has to keep asking for credentials, so my thoughts are to run a thread, which will keep checking to see if i need a login or not, but i keep getting errors like cross-threading and all, ie launching a thread from a different thread...at least thats my understanding of it, any thoughts?

Comment: @MakarEmelyanov Try using the [BackGroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the help, ended up doing something rather different. but i do have another question, im trying to run a sub or function when the application starts, im doing this so that all the data from an xml file is uploaded to the application before any events have to occur. question is how do i do that ha

Comment: @Makar do it in the initializer, in vb it is the New Sub

Comment: would you be able to give me an example? thanks for all the help btw mate :)

Comment: actually i think i have a way of doing it through a module

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project, choose `Add > New Item...` in the menu.

Then choose `Dialog` in the list.

You can add any control that you like to your dialog, and as Mark said, you can open it using `ShowDialog`.

Comment: wow loads of great suggestions, thanks very much to everyone, i shall try and see which one suits best for the application :) also seeing as were helping poor 'ol me here (ha) how can i input credentials to a site without having to open a browser, is it done like entering an ftp url where u can put user, pass and then the link to the server? orrrrr...